# cant get model from route action in ember

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data, ember-router, ember-controllers

i just wanna refresh model in route while get an action from controller and run doRefresh action in this route

this is my code

```
    import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  profileFormService: Ember.inject.service(),
  profileFormAtributeService: Ember.inject.service(),
  model(){
    return Ember.RSVP.hash({
      profileForms: this.get('profileFormService').find(),
      profileFormsAttributes: this.get('profileFormAtributeService').findByProfileFormId("1"),
      inputTypes: {data: ['CHECKBOX', 'NUMBER_FIELD', 'PHONE_NUMBER', 'TEXT_FIELD', 'EMAIL', 'TEXT_AREA', 'RADIO_BUTTON', 'DESA', 'KABUPATEN_KOTA', 'PROVINSI', 'KECAMATAN', 'MAP_POINT', 'MAP_POLYGON']}
    });
  },
  setupController(controller, model) {
    this.controllerFor('backend.setting-profile-form-attribute').set('profileForms', model.profileForms);
    this.controllerFor('backend.setting-profile-form-attribute').set('profileFormsAttributes', model.profileFormsAttributes);
    this.controllerFor('backend.setting-profile-form-attribute').set('inputTypes', model.inputTypes);
  },
  actions:{
    doRefresh(param){
      let context = this;
      this.get('profileFormAtributeService').findByProfileFormId(param).then(function (response) {
        context.set("profileFormsAttributes",response);
      }), function (e) {
        this.debug(e);
      };
    }
  }
});
```

unfortunately this is does'nt affect the profileFormsAttributes model.

I've ben trying to debug the model with this

```
this.debug(this.get('controller.model.profileFormsAttributes'))
this.debug(this.get('model.profileFormsAttributes'));
```

but the console log said undefined

can you resolve this and explain what happen in this my route..

thank's for your concern

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you cannot achieve the object returned from within route in action handler directly like `this.get('profileFormsAttributes')`; hence your setting does not work.

```
this.get('controller.model.profileFormsAttributes');
this.get('model.profileFormsAttributes');
```

Even above two statements does not work; because you cannot retrieve `model` or `controller` like this.

You have two options; either you need to save what you are going to return from model directly within `model` hook with `this.set('model', model)` or you can achieve it with `this.controllerFor(this.get('routeName')).get('model')`

I would recommend the second approach for your case. Please take a look at the following [twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/fb7816da037e3f018af35dcc6a056a00?openFiles=routes.index.js%2Ctemplates.components.my-component.hbs) that I have prepared to illustrate the case for you.

Please take a look at `index.js` where `foo` attribute of object returned from `model` hook is set with

```
Ember.set(this.controllerFor(this.get('routeName')).get('model'), 'foo', 'foo updated');
```

I hope this helps.